# Laravel Elixir sass dependency path

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, npm, sass

I'm using laravel 5.2 with elixir.
I have an error when I use bootstrap-material-design with bootstrap-sass, the gulp task return this :

```
gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Sass Compilation Failed: node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/sass/_import-bs-sass.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap/variables
       Parent style sheet: /workspace/node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/sass/_import-bs-sass.scss
       on line 1 of node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/sass/_import-bs-sass.scss
>> @import "bootstrap/variables";
```

When I replace the line with this, it works.

```
@import "../../bootstrap-material-design/sass/variables";
```

In my gulpfile I've got :

```
elixir(function(mix) {
mix
    .browserSync({
        proxy : 'http'
    })
    .sass('app.scss')
    .browserify('app.js')
    .version(["public/css/app.css","public/js/app.js"]);
});
```

In my app.scss I've got :

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/sass/bootstrap-material-design";
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, here is my `gulpfile.js`

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix
        .browserSync({
            proxy : 'http'
        })
        .sass('app.scss', "public/css/app.css", {
            includePaths: ['node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/']
        })
        .browserify('app.js')
        .version(["public/css/app.css","public/js/app.js"]);
});
```